# Apache Mod Rewrite -- fake a folder when infact there is one

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have, let's say, www.website.org/folder/ which inside has the following `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^folder/[0-9]+ http://www.website.org/folder/index.php?n=$1 [NC]
```

inside `folder` I have many folders like `1234`, `4567`, etc. The behavior I'm looking for is a rewriting from `www.website.org/folder/1234` to `www.website.org/folder/index.php?n=1234`. However, for some reason the rewriting doesn't occur and I get a Forbidden error (given that you can't access the directory itself).

How can I solve this?
Thank you very much

-- Note: I had to put away `Options +FollowSymlinks` because I was getting a `Option FollowSymLinks not allowed here` error from the provider's webserver.

**-- Edit 1**

Following Jason's post I modified the .htaccess as follows (I still kept it in `folder`):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder/
RewriteRule ^folder/([0-9]+)/?$ /folder/index.php?n=$1 [NC,L]
```

But it still brings me to the folder, why is this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way your rule is written, **.htaccess** should be in your webroot not the `folder` directory.

Alternatively, you could modify your `RewriteBase`. However, I'd do the above and use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^folder/([0-9]+)/?$ /folder/index.php?n=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Might add parentheses around the `[0-9]+`, so that `$1` means something.

Comment: I believe having .htaccess in `folder` is what's throwing you off.

Comment: Make sure you removed your old .htaccess file and are correctly writing your URL in your HTML links.